# My Excel VBA Stops running even there is no error prompt (Selecting a folder)

Tags: excel, vba

I have s sub procedure which is calling a function named SelectFolder. Whenever I run the code, it just steps whenever I finished selecting a folder without saying any error. I even tried including "Application.EnableEvents = True" and "Application.DisplayAlerts = True" but nothing really works.

It always happen when in the line .Show after I selected a folder
What can be the reason for this?

Sub Procedure:

```
TargetFolder = SelectFolder("Please select folder")
```

Function:

```
Function SelectFolder(title_message)
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = title_message
        .Show
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .SelectedItems.count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
            Exit Function
        End If
        SelectFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: SelectFolder = .SelectedItems(1) isn't this line used for returning a value to TargetFolder? I run through the code, and it always ends in the .Show line and me picking a folder then VBA just stops altogether without an error

Comment: Sorry, my earlier comment got deleted accidentally. Yes, you are right. What I wanted to say was try specifying the return datatype in your function as  `Function SelectFolder(title_message) As String`. Neverthless I did try your code and it is working fine for me without any change.

Comment: Sure, I will include that. Yes, that's really weird. That function is used by other sub procedure and running correctly

Comment: Please add this line `Debug.Print TargetFolder` after the function call line and see what is the output. That way,we can ascertain if the error lies somewhere else and not in function.

Comment: TargetFolder = SelectFolder("Please select the folder of source files")
Debug.Print TargetFolder and Function SelectFolder(title_message) As String

i've done this and still it stops without an error

Comment: It's working now. I just included "/" in the targetfolder 'TargetFolder = SelectFolder("") & "/"'.

Comment: Okay. Glad to hear.